# Taking data from Excel and inserting into a pre existing Word table?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I know this has been asked previously, but I can only find sites which create the table in Word as you transfer the data.

I have a Word document with 3 tables and want to extract data from an Excel file sent by a client into certain cells within the Word tables. 
E.G I would like to take the content of cell D3 in Excel and put it in cell 2,2 in the second table in Word? Is there a way to reference which table to insert the data?

Can anyone help with this or just push me in the right direction as I am relatively new to Macros etc. As we use the Word document and have the Excel file sent to us, would making the Macro in Word be more beneficial or not?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to identify the tables by their `.Name` property. Then you can refer to the table's `.Cell(2,2).Shape.Text = "some value"` (or something like this -- I'm not in a position to test so I'm writing from memory.  If this is all you need to do, whether you choose to bind Excel to Word or Word to Excel is a matter of preference, really.

Comment: Cheers David, but forgive me for being a bit stupid - how do I assign a .Name property to a table that already exists?

Comment: you can iterate through each shape in the `InlineShapes` collection using `For each shp in ActiveDocument.InlineShapes` then check: `If shp.HasTable Then Debug.Print shp.Name`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for you help David, you gave me a push in the right direction. It wasn't in `InlineShapes` but under, believe it or not, `Tables`. I can't believe I missed it the first time round of doing it. Thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help, even if I was mistaken (Tables are a member of the `Shapes` collection in PowerPoint which is where I do most of my VBA these days, but you're right they are a separate `Tables` collection in Word).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to fix it and typically it is relatively simple, but thanks to @David Zemens for the push in the right direction. I don't know how I missed the "Tables" bit out when searching through "ThisDocument" previously.

```
 Sub GetData()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExcelFileName As String

ExcelFileName = "{Put the directory of Excel file here}"
Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)

'Set the text of the cell from Excel to the cell in the specified table in Word (the second table in this instance)
ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = exWb.Sheets("Test").Cells(2, 1)

' Close Excel bits
exWb.Close
Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```